# Minimum Height Trees. Why does deleting leaves layer-by-layer give us the answer?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

Here is the [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-height-trees/description/) I tried to solve. Finally, I gave up and found a solution which was correct. Here is [it.](http://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-height-trees/discuss/76104/C++-Solution.-O(n)-Time-O(n)-Space/79548)

Here is the problem description:

> For a undirected graph with tree characteristics, we can choose any
>   node as the root. The result graph is then a rooted tree. Among all
>   possible rooted trees, those with minimum height are called minimum
>   height trees (MHTs). Given such a graph, write a function to find all
>   the MHTs and return a list of their root labels.
>
> The graph contains n nodes which are labeled from 0 to n - 1. You will
>   be given the number n and a list of undirected edges (each edge is a
>   pair of labels).
>
> You can assume that no duplicate edges will appear in edges. Since all
>   edges are undirected, [0, 1] is the same as [1, 0] and thus will not
>   appear together in edges.

**Example 1 :**

Input: n = 4, edges = [[1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3]]

```
    0
    |
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

Output: 1

**Example 2 :**

Input: n = 6, edges = [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [4, 3], [5, 4]]

```
 0  1  2
  \ | /
    3
    |
    4
    |
    5
```

Output: 3, 4

Here is the solution I tried to understand:

> The basic idea is "keep deleting leaves layer-by-layer, until reach
>   the root."
>
> Specifically, first find all the leaves, then remove them. After
>   removing, some nodes will become new leaves. So we can continue remove
>   them. Eventually, there is only 1 or 2 nodes left. If there is only
>   one node left, it is the root. If there are 2 nodes, either of them
>   could be a possible root.

I'm not sure I understand it so I could explain it to somebody. Why does deleting leaves layer-by-layer give us the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $T$ be a tree, and let $T'$ be the tree formed from $T$ by removing all leaves (vertices of degree 1). Assume that $T$ contains at least three vertices, so that $T'$ is not empty. This implies that every leaf $f \in T$ has a (unique) neighbor $p(f) \in T$ which is not a leaf.

For $v \in T$, denote by $h_v(T)$ the height of $T$ when rooted at $v$.
I claim that the following hold:

> For every vertex $v \in T'$, $$ h_v(T) = h_v(T') + 1. $$
>   For every leaf $f \in T \setminus T'$, $$ h_f(T) = h_{p(f)}(T) + 1. $$

For the first claim, consider $T$ rooted at a non-leaf $v$. The height of $T$ is the length of the maximal root-to-leaf path. Every such path gets shortened by one in $T'$, implying that $h_v(T) = h_v(T') + 1$.

For the second claim, let $x$ be a leaf farthest away from $p(f)$. We can assuming that $x \neq f$ since $p(f)$ has at least two neighbors, and $f$ is at minimal distance from $p(f)$. Clearly $d(f,x) = d(p(f),x) + 1$, and so $h_f(T) \geq h_{p(f)}(T) + 1$. The other direction follows from the triangle inequality, which implies that $d(f,y) \leq d(p(f),y) + 1$ for all nodes $y$.

**The algorithm.** If $T$ contains one or two vertices, then clearly all vertices are *centers* (roots of minimum height trees). Otherwise, by the second claim, no leaf can be a center, and so by the first claim, the centers of $T$ are the same as the centers of $T'$. This suggests the following algorithm for computing the centers of $T$:

> 1. While $T$ contains at least three vertices, remove all leaves of $T$.
> 2. Once $T$ contains one or two vertices, return all vertices of $T$.

The correctness of the algorithm follows the reasoning stated above.

Comment: Beautiful explanation.